# MyEtherWallet and Ethereum Wallet

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet

My questions:

1. Are MyEtherWallet and Ethereum Wallet same?
2. Is it possible to keep multiple crypto currencies including  bitcoin, Ethereum and others in a single wallet? Or do I need separate wallets for each crypto currencies?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid asking to questions in the same question.

1. Myetherwallet is a web site (https://www.myetherwallet.com) while 'Ethereum wallet' is a generic name for any wallet. As a wallet, you can use the wallet provided on https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases or myetherwallet or any other ethereum wallet.
2. It depends on what kind of cryptocurrency you want to keep.
   On an ethereum wallet, you can keep ether and any ethereum token
   (as ethereum allow you to create other cryptocurrencies on the ethereum blockchain). But if you want to keep independant cryptocurrencies with their own blockchain, like bitcoin core, bitcoin cash or any other cryptocurrency,
   you will need a wallet for each of them.

On wallets :

- Note that exchanges, that is website where you do not have the private key of your ether, are not proper wallet. If they disappear, there be will no technical way for you to get your money back. Basically, you will have to sue them.
- Your ether is not "in" your wallet. It is at your address/public key.
  So you can use as many wallet as you want and keep the exact same ether on it.
  But in this case, your are exposed to flaws of every wallet you use.